# Jquery check 2 radio button on once click

Tags: jquery

I am facing problem with radio button check and uncheck.
We have 4 radio buttons of which 2 are named as artist and 2 customer.

Whenever I click 1 artist button I also want to show the other as selected as well and vice versa. My code is:

First DIV:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad1" name="data[User][role1]" value="artist" checked="checked"><label for="radio1">Artist</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad2" name="data[User][role1]" value="user"><label for="radio2">Customer</label>
</div>
```

Second DIV:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio11" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad1" name="data[User][role2]" value="artist" checked="checked"><label for="radio11">Artist</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio21" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad2" name="data[User][role2]" value="user"><label for="radio21">Customer</label>
</div>
```

<strike>Thanks in advance please help::</strike>

```
$(document).on('change','.chooseprofile',function(){
  var userType = $(this).val();
    if(userType == 'artist') {  
        $(document.body).find('.rad1').prop('checked', 'checked');
        $(document.body).find('.rad2').removeAttr('checked');
    }else{
            $(document.body).find('.rad2').prop('checked', 'checked');
            $(document.body).find('.rad1').removeAttr('checked');
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code?

Comment: $(document).on('change','.chooseprofile',function(){ 
    var userType = $(this).val();
    if(userType == 'artist') { 
        $(document.body).find('.rad1').prop('checked', 'checked');
        $(document.body).find('.rad2').removeAttr('checked');
        
    } else {
        $(document.body).find('.rad2').prop('checked', 'checked');
        $(document.body).find('.rad1').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('input.chooseprofile').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('rad1')) {
      jQuery('input.chooseprofile.rad1').prop('checked', true);
      jQuery('input.chooseprofile.rad2').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
      jQuery('input.chooseprofile.rad1').prop('checked', false);
      jQuery('input.chooseprofile.rad2').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First DIV:
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad1" name="data[User][role1]" value="artist" checked="checked"><label for="radio1">Artist</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad2" name="data[User][role1]" value="user"><label for="radio2">Customer</label>
</div>

Second DIV:

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio11" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad1" name="data[User][role2]" value="artist" checked="checked"><label for="radio11">Artist</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="radio21" type="radio" class ="chooseprofile rad2" name="data[User][role2]" value="user"><label for="radio21">Customer</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of losing fingers writing `jQuery` all over the place: `jQuery(function( $ ) { /*now use $ as jQuery alias */ });`

Comment: Good point. Although I found it easier for people to understand the code when jQuery and $ is not being intermixed. And you can't go `$(function(...` because he may be running jQuery in safe-mode. (as is default case in WP installs). In any case, that's a correct and well placed remark. Thanks.

Comment: exactly, so when doing WP (if I'm not missing something) you simply go as I've said :) pass the alias $ as argument.